# Spark sql limit in IN clause

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I have a query in `spark-sql` with a lot of values in the IN clause:

```
select * from table where x in (<long list of values>)
```

When i run this query i get a `TransportException` from the `MetastoreClient` in `spark`.
Column x is the partition column of the table. The hive metastore is on Oracle.

Is there a hard limit on how many values can be in the in clause?
Or can i maybe set the timeout value higher to give the metastore more time to answer.

Comment: I would suggest to create dataframe from that list and use join. This way you will know if there is no other issue.

Comment: dataframe for values as gorros sugests, and broadcast this dataframe for increase performance.

Answer (score 4):

yes,you can pass upto 1000 values inside IN clause.
However, you can use OR operator inside IN clause and slice the list of values into multiple 1000 windows.

Comment: can you share the example?

Comment: Where is this documented? Is this a limit on the IN clause?